# pre/post increment operator on OutputIterator

Tags: c++, stl, stream, iterator

I read in an article on `OutputIterator` that we only can dereference  it as lvalue. My question is about `operator++` which increments the iterator by one position.

So,

```
*it++ = t
```

would be

```
{*it = t; ++it; }
```

https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/OutputIterator.html

Now, I am assuming that `operator++` would be overloaded in such a fashion that it would increment `OutputIterator` by one position.

`ostream_iterator` is also an `OutputIterator` and implements all the requirements of `OutputIterator`.

Then why is `operator++` implemented as shown below in `ostream_iterator`?

```
ostream_iterator<T,charT,traits>& operator++() { return *this; }
ostream_iterator<T,charT,traits>& operator++(int) { return *this; }
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/

That shows `operator++` does nothing.

Does dereferencing the output operator assign a new value and advance it by one position? Without using `operator++`?

If so, then why do we need to implement `operator++`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The use of this operator is formal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator_arith). An `OutputIterator` must support the `++`-operator regardless if it has any effect.

Comment: Thanks. then How does the iterator is getting incremented if ++ operator does nothing ?can you please clarify this one

Comment: See the link you provided and follow the explanation of the ++-operator (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ostream_iterator/operator++/): Streams just _"advance automatically on insertion"_.

Comment: @YADAV `ostream_iterator::operator=` is where the increment happens, but even there it happens indirectly. When `operator=` writes a value to the `ostream` that the iterator is wrapping, the stream automatically advances after inserting the value.

Comment: Thanks @Praetorian . now i got my answer.

Comment: Have one small doubt here , why SGI link says ++x  :x points to the next location into which a value may be stored.   i am bit confused

Comment: Yes. It is the post condition where this is said. But it does not say that x is changed.

Comment: @YADAV In other words, that statement is true because  after `++x;`, `x` does point to the next location where a value can be inserted. The post-condition doesn't say something like *`++x` causes `x` to skip the location where the value would've been inserted prior to the call to `++x`*